# ¿Por que los iconos mis iconos con jQuery Validation Plugin se posición debajo del input?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jquery-validate

Tome [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/dark_diesel/gzmwtvh3/) y alli funciona perfecto, pero en mi sistema no.

Aca el Form mio:

```
                    <div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content"> 
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-tittle">Crear</h4>
                                </div>
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="CrearNombre" class="control-label col-sm-2">Nombre: </label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="CrearNombre" name="CrearNombre">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cerrar 
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="submit" id="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            <span class="fa fa-save"> Guardar</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Aca mi jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
            }
        }
    });
    $( "#form-crear" ).validate({
        rules: {
            CrearNombre: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

y mi resultado es:

[image: jquery validation plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que haz envuelto el input con un extra `<div>`:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="CrearNombre" name="CrearNombre">
</div>
```

Entonces esta linea:

```
$(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
```

Hace que te lo mete después del extra `<div>` y te lo desconfigura.

**Solución:**

Metes una clase llamado `extraDiv` por ejemplo:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 extraDiv">
  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="CrearNombre" name="CrearNombre">
</div>
```

y cambias la clase en `validator`:

```
$(element).closest('.extraDiv').append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
```

[Ver Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gzmwtvh3/116/)

Comment: ¿y como hago para q el texto que esta abajo, el mensaje del error (ej: "This field is required."), se coloque en rojo tambien?

Comment: @PabloContreras - pon en tu css `.error { color: red; }`

Comment: no me funciono con ".error" probe con ".has-error" y si funciono.

Comment: @PabloContreras - A mi si me funciono: [ver](https://jsfiddle.net/gzmwtvh3/117/)

Comment: con la sugerencia que me diste, me aparece lo siguiente:
goo.gl/Vnomsa

Comment: que extraño, debo tener algun plugin que esta influyendo mis css :(

Comment: @PabloContreras - No te puedo decir ahora más en la demo funciona y es eso vamos... pero no se lo que te puede fallar ahora... Lo que puedes probar es quitar el div *extra* dejar el *validator* como estaba y pruebas: [como aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/gzmwtvh3/118/) y luego te queda a ajustar el estilo

Comment: ahora me aparece asi
goo.gl/EfwVoccontent_copyCopy short URL